# Size of Maximum Matching in Bipartite Graph

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching

Am I correct in my observation that the cardinality of the maximum matching $M$ of a bipartite graph $G(U, V, E)$ is always equal to $\min(|U|, |V|)$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given a bipartite graph $G = (U,V,E)$ and a maximum matching $M$ of $G$, via [Konig's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29) we see that $|M| = |C|$ where $C$ is a minimum vertex cover for $G$. Your statement is merely an upper bound on the size of the possible matching, not a strict equality.

The image on the wikipedia page provides a nice counterexample to your claim. We see that $|M| = 6$, while $\min(|U|,|V|) = 7$.

[image]

However, in the case of a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,m}$ your statement holds.

Answer (score 9):

No. For example, consider the case where the two sides are disconnected $|E| = 0$ or the case where a large group of nodes are all connected to the same single node:

$U = u_1, u_2, ..., u_n$

$V = v_1, v_2, ... , v_n$

$E = u_1v_1, u_2v_1, ... u_nv_1,$
$     v_1u_1, v_2u_1, ... v_nu_1$

Comment: of course. man next time i need to try to think first, before i ask something here.